# How to tell typescript that map.get will always return a value?

Tags: typescript

`map` is an instance of `Map`. In this code I want to create new `[key, value]` pair if it doesn't already exist and then edit `propertyInValue`

```
if (!map.has(key)) { 
    map.set(key, new Value())
}
map.get(key).propertyInValue = doSomething()
```

I get an error `Object is possibly 'undefined'` on `map.get(key)`

Can I somehow tell TypeScript to not worry about it? Can it be done in tsconfig.json?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured it out.

[Non-null assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) saves the day!

```
map.get(key)!.propertyInValue = doSomething()
```

Also possible to set `"strictNullChecks": false` in `tsconfig.json`

Comment: the only problem you open the code for bugs in case the value is null or undefined. I think if you use the code below would safer.

let a = map.get(key) || new Value();
a.propertyInValue = doSomething()

Comment: @TomášWróbel, I am sorry but that was rude. They didn't know the answer first. Then they searched more and found the answer and showed it here. If anyone, in future, has the same query, they can refer to this answer. Even, in Stack Overflow's beginner's guide, it is said: "you can answer your own question".

Moreover, their answer is perfectly correct according their question. The goal was to tell TS - "Don't worry. I ensure `map.get()` will never return an `undefined`" and that's why Non-null assertion is used.

Comment: @AlanLins Well, if you do a `.has(key)` check before hand like in the question then it won't be `undefined`. TypeScript works if you do a check like this before a possibly `undefined` value so I think it should work if you do a `.has(key)` check before a `.get(key)`.

Comment: Found some chat here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13086

Answer (score -4):

```
(map.get(key) as any).propertyInValue = doSomething()
```

or

```
let a = map.get(key) || new Value();
a.propertyInValue = doSomething()
```

Comment: Using any is not good practice. It will turn off type checking for the statement. Non-null assertion is much much better